# Using Class or Implemented interface is non API on version '2.4.4'

Tags: magento2.4, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4, interface, magento-graphql

I have generated **Upgrade Compatibility Tool Report** and most of the errors are as below.

> [ERROR] [1328]
> Line 24: Implemented interface 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface' that is non API on version '2.4.4'

> [ERROR] [1124]
> Line 79: Using class 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field' that is non API on version '2.4.4'

> [ERROR] [1124]
> Line 81: Using class 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo' that is non API on version '2.4.4'

> [ERROR] [1124]
> Line 87: Using class 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException' that is non API on version '2.4.4'

> [ERROR] [1124]
> Line 94: Using class 'Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException' that is non API on version '2.4.4'

[image]

These are core classes that we need when working with Graphql. I am not able to find any alternative solutions.

Please help.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I also stuck in a same issue please let me know if you find anything

Comment: We upgraded to 2.4.5 and the above issues were resolved. But there are still alot of different issues that we do not see any solution as of now.

Comment: Ohk Thanks for the update @Kaushik. We got solutions for non API error for some files like curlInterface, request interface etc. but we rely on Magento that after upgrading all will work well.

Comment: @Ankit can you provide solution for curlInterface,request interface etc

Comment: Can you ask in question please can not paste so much in comments.@Vishal

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360206/using-class-magento-shipping-model-shipmentnotifier-that-is-non-api-on-version

Comment: @KaushikKumarRoy any idea about on this "non API on version" why its occurring?

Answer (score 1):

These files are in magento codebase, so you don't need to fix them. If you still would like to fix these issues, mark that class as @api in docblock.

Example:

```
/**
 * Schema object for a GraphQL endpoint describing queries and types for a client to consume.
 *
 * @api
 */
class Schema extends \GraphQL\Type\Schema
{
}
```