# Using class 'Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier' that is non API on version '2.4.5'

Tags: magento2.4.5

I have upgraded to 2.4.5 and run UCT tool but shows los of error related to core file
Ex:
Extending from class 'Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper' that is non API on version '2.4.5'
Using class 'Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier' that is non API on version '2.4.5'

Answer (score 0):

These files are in magento codebase (core), so you don't need to fix them. If you still would like to fix these issues, mark that class as @api in docblock.

Example:

```
/**
 * Schema object for a GraphQL endpoint describing queries and types for a client to consume.
 *
 * @api
 */
class Schema extends \GraphQL\Type\Schema
{
}
```